# ADB wont show debug info for certain device

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I have always used my Meizu m2 note for development and it always worked.
Recently, I updated it and since them, I cant get logs in logcat. No exceptions, just this stuff whatever the hell it is:

```
09-11 11:02:32.940 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.soundcloud.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
09-11 11:02:32.940 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
09-11 11:02:32.940 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.soundcloud.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
09-11 11:02:32.940 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
09-11 11:02:32.997 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: api.soundcloud.com get result from proxy >>
09-11 11:02:33.131 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=api.soundcloud.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
09-11 11:02:33.132 5262-5301/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
09-11 11:02:34.086 5262-5334/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=i1.sndcdn.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
09-11 11:02:34.086 5262-5334/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
09-11 11:02:34.087 5262-5334/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=i1.sndcdn.com; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
09-11 11:02:34.087 5262-5334/net.oneread.spplayer D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
```

I am sure it it not related to problem.
So I went to DDMS and this is what I see:
[image]

There is no hierarchy and and exception that you see. I tried restarting ADB but nothing helps. Developer mode is also enabled.
I suspect this is on this specific device because it works on emulator, but I have not been able to come around other devices to test.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

After whole day of searching and trying, I finally had to reset my phone to factory settings and erase all data. Now it works as before.

Comment: I also read that some Chinese phones have debugging locked. More often with Xiaomi. I don't get the reason behind it. The real question is: can debugging feature be unlocked before an update fix? Still have not found the answer to that.